# NPM Package XLSX | Read Data In empty Columns | When Column next to empty Column has data

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sheetjs

I have XLS which has data in format

[Data in XLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuKdy.png)

I want to read column A which does not have data but i do not want to read any column after D because it does not have any data.

I want to also include column A in my results because the data exists after this column.

Below code snippet i am using

```
import { read, utils, writeFileXLSX } from 'xlsx';

const f = await (await fetch("http://localhost:3001/experiment.csv")).arrayBuffer();
 
const type = "array";
const wb = read(f, { type }); 
const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]]; 

const rows = utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: "A" ,  defval }); 

  /* create column array */
  const range = utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"]||"A1");
  const columns = Array.from({ length: range.e.c + 1 }, (_, i) => ({
  key: i, 
  name: utils.encode_col(i), // the column labels will be A, B, etc
}));

  
console.log('All Row rows=',rows,'columns2=',columns);
```

When i print rows, it does not have data for column A. What options should i use in

```
utils.sheet_to_json
```

to read column A.

Any help is appreciated.